# AjaxControlToolkit does not work for pages using MasterPage

Tags: ajax, master-pages, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-4.5

I've been trying to get the AjaxControlToolkit (downloaded from NuGet) version 7.0607 to work for web forms that use a masterpage with no luck.
Running DotNet 4.5
The MasterPage has the ToolkitScriptManager on it, but it does not pass down to child pages.

I can create a standalone aspx page, drop a scriptmanager on the page and the controls work just fine, so I figure there is a setting missing.

What is the procedure for making this work?

The masterpage script block is as so:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Name="ExtenderBase.BaseScripts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Name="Common.Common.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
        </Scripts>
    </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Comment: Show master page's markup

Comment: What Yuriy said--I've never had an issue with ToolkitScriptManager on a Master Page not being accessible from the child.

Comment: Here's the header:

    <%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.vb" Inherits="TinySearch.SiteMaster" %>


Sorry - there's no room to post the whole page.

Comment: I'll try and create another temporary project - it may be another bug in MS's start up template (there's quite a few).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no bug, just bad advice from another forum.
The following lines were the culprit - either one messes up things:

```
<asp:ScriptReference Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Name="ExtenderBase.BaseScripts.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Name="Common.Common.js" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the Microsoft script manager with toolkit script manger did the trick for me and they are working.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
```

with

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```